# How to access data from `std::ostringstream` without copying it

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostringstream

I'm using `std::ostringstream` to serialize data to send it through sockets later. Now I'm using `std::ostringstream::str()` function to get access to the data, but I would like to avoid copying the data.

Is this possible to get access to the underlying data buffer in `std::ostringstream` (const char* or something similar)?

Comment: Are you unable to store the string returned by `str()` somewhere and pass that instead?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo calling str() creates a copy - I would like to avoid this.